# Query another schema on a different sid Oracle

Tags: oracle, schema

I have 3 db's that should be in sync with each other, but there are some differences that I am trying to rectify.  We try to stay out of the main schema and do all of our work on a separate user schema, the data is then streamed around if updates are made.

I need to be able to query data on a different schema on a different sid to get the tables in sync, but I get an `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied` when I do so.

For example when I am logged in as schema2 on sid1:

```
/* works */
select * from schema1.my_table@sid1

/* throws an error */
select * from schema1.my_table@sid2
```

Likewise when I am logged in as schema2 on sid2

```
/* works */
select * from schema1.my_table@sid2

/* throws an error */
select * from schema1.my_table@sid1
```

Is this type of query possible?  There is already a database link created between the db's.  I use connect through when I log on so I do not know the schema2 password and I am afraid to change it.  Is it that they are different on all three nodes?

I hope this is making sense, please ask for any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database links are configured with the wrong passwords.

Comment: Ok, this looks like what it most likely is.  So this means I have to update this password every time I update my oracle password, they are the same ones correct?

Comment: Yes. If you change the account password, you must update everything that uses it to use the new value.